# Why do all of my resource files contain TrayLocation? Is it Sisulizer's fault?

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

In our C# WinForms application we are encountering some localisation issues: A large number of our .resx files appear to have an entry for "control.TrayLocation" in them, with a value specifying a point location (e.g. 17, 58). This is very unusual, as typically these kind of properties are added to the resource file with a name starting with '>>' to indicate they are a form property.

This might be related to the fact we are using Sisulizer to do our translations, as it could potentially have added a property to the .resx, but it is a bit hard to determine if this is the cause.

Has anybody else experienced the same issue with WinForms and Sisulizer

Comment: Is this releated to http://www.sisulizer.net/forum4/3622.html. If so then the >> scanning bug does not solve the issue but the problem is that Sisulizer scans that point valeu as string and not as point. When it is string then translator can enter any value an in your case the Chinese value as incorrect. Just remove those Chinese translations or exclude or mark as do not translate all TrayLocation rows.

Answer (score 1):

Note: In the interest of full disclosure, I'm the author of TranSolution, a localization program for Visual Studio developers (and therefore a competitor of Sisulizer). This isn't necessarily something Sisulizer added (though it's possible). MSFT adds this property on its own when you create a tray control, which is just a non-visual control that appears in the "tray" area seen at the bottom of the Visual Studio forms designer. IOW, it's not normally a "System.Windows.Forms.Control" derivative, i.e., a GUI control. It's some other non-visual control associated with your form or user control, such as a "System.Data.DataSet" for instance (and therefore not part of what an end-user actually sees). In the forms designer, try dragging a "DataSet" from the "Toolbox" onto your form for instance. It will appear in the area at the bottom of the designer window (the "tray" area), and the "TrayLocation" property therefore shows you its location in that area. You'll even notice in the ".resx" file that this property is a "metadata" element, not a "data" element (like most other elements in a ".resx" file). "metadata" in this context normally refers to additional properties not normally associated with the control (additional properties can be added to any .NET object on-the-fly, but this is a long story). These particular properties are used by Visual Studio itself normally, so you won't find them documented as part of the actual control in MSDN. Note BTW that the ">>" you referred to actually designates one of 4 special MSFT properties associated with a form or user control, namely:

>>ControlName.Name

>>ControlName.Type

>>ControlName.Parent

>>ControlName.ZOrder

These have nothing to do with a tray control however (they're present for a form or user control only normally). They aren't even officially documented by MSFT in fact (last time I checked), though much of what you find in form-based ".resx" files isn't documented. You can find a quasi-official explanation of these properties here however https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rprabhu/2003/08/21/winres/ (from someone who worked on the forms team at MSFT).

Lastly, note that handling these properties and other situations in a 3rd-party localization program may not always be done correctly depending on the program. I can't speak to what Sisulizer is doing (presumably they're handling things correctly for you), but from my own experience, it took a lot of work to track this down once upon a time (again, since much of what goes on in a form-based ".resx" file isn't documented by MSFT).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same issues two weeks ago and reported the issue to Sisulizer. They fixed the issue and when using the newest build (361) Sisulizer no longer adds these >>xxxx resource items.